# Qt - draw inside QScrollArea in a QDialog

Tags: qt, drawing, qpainter, qdialog, qscrollarea

In `Qt`5, I have a `QDialog` window on which I have drawn a circle as follows:

```
void MyDialog::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *pe)
{
       QPainter painter(this);
       painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing,true);
       QPen pen(Qt::blue,2);
       painter.setPen(pen);
       QRect r=QRect(0,0,100,100);
       painter.drawEllipse(r);
}
```

If I draw a larger circle, for example by using `QRect(0,0,500,500);`, the circle being greater than the dialog window is clipped. So I dragged a `QScrollArea` onto the the dialog window and decide to draw onto that so that scroll bars are automatically added. The `QScrollArea` can be accessed using `ui->scrollArea`.

I changed the above code by setting `QPainter painter(ui->scrollArea);`. However, nothings appears in the `QScrollArea`. I read that I need to override the `paintEvent` of `QScrollArea`. But I don't know how to do this.

Any help of drawing on the `QScrollArea`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drawing on the QScrollArea is not what you want either because the QScrollArea actually has a viewport widget.

Create another class which inherits QWidget. Override the paintEvent() method and to the painting you mention. Then, add the widget to the scroll area in your dialog.

```
MyDialog::MyDialog()
{
  QScrollArea *pScrl = new QScrollArea(this);
  pScrl->setWidget(new MyWidget(pScrl));
  ... // use a layout to put the scroll area in the dialog
}
```

To really make it useful you will need to resize the MyWidget instance to the size of the circle that you want to draw.